# PHP IP address range validation

Tags: php, ip

I am setting up trialpay for my website. The website shows :

Requests originate from the following IP address range: 70.42.249.1 - 70.42.249.255

In PHP, how do I check to see if the bot/person visiting my auth page falls within the above IP range?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with ip addresses, it's probably easier to treat them as integers instead of strings. You can use the [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function to do this.

Here's a working function to help you out:

```
function ipbetweenrange($needle, $start, $end) {
  if((ip2long($needle) >= ip2long($start)) && (ip2long($needle) <= ip2long($end))) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

$ipstart = '70.42.249.1';
$ipend = '70.42.249.255';

echo ipbetweenrange('70.42.249.1', $ipstart, $ipend); // true
echo ipbetweenrange('70.42.249.255', $ipstart, $ipend); // true
echo ipbetweenrange('70.42.249.128', $ipstart, $ipend); // true
echo ipbetweenrange('192.168.0.1', $ipstart, $ipend); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( range( 1, 255 ) as $number )
{

    if( $userIp == '70.42.249.' . $number )
        // we have a match, do whatever you want

}
```

Something along those lines. And yes, this should probably be moved to Stackoverflow.